# I want to deploy my text scraping program to Heroku, but the file it uses is stored on my PC

Tags: python, django, heroku

I created a text scraping program in which the user enters a word and it searches through a large text file (250MG and growing) on my computer, but now I want to deploy it through Heroku.

Is there a workaround that I need to implement or is there a (rather elusive) way to accomplish this? As far as I can tell, there is no way to upload my text file to Heroku as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggestion.

1. Host the text file on a site like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com) as long as it doesn't contain any confidential information. This allows you to update it freely without needing to re-deploy your app each time you add to it.
2. Once you've uploaded/pasted the text into a "paste" & save it you'll be able to get the "raw" link that will return the content of the file when requested.
3. Use `requests` to fetch the file from your app & parse it however you need to.

   ```
   import requests
   resp = requests.get("https://pastebin.com/raw/LjcPg3UL")
   # if all entries are on individual lines
   mywords = [word for word in resp.iter_lines()]
   # if comma-separated or otherwise
   #mywords = resp.text.split(",")
   ```

Now you have all your content in a list to work with in your app.

**Edit:**
Since you want to accomplish this with larger files you could host the file on dropbox and follow the instructions from [here](https://milanaryal.com.np/direct-linking-to-your-files-on-dropbox-google-drive-and-onedrive/) to get the raw link. However, if you're dealing with that large of a file you're going to notice significant overhead. If the file is going to be that large, I'd suggest the added precaution of utilizing `requests` `stream` parameter ([details](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/user/advanced/#body-content-workflow)), so the request line becomes

```
resp = requests.get("https://www.dropbox.com/s/FILE_ID/filename.extension?raw=1", stream=True)
```

This will read chunks of the file instead of reading the entire file at once, which will help cut down of memory consumption.

Comment: Pastebin has a limit of 500 KB per file or 10 MB if I get a pro account. The file I am searching through may grow up to 1 GB. Do you know of any other resources I could use to accomplish this?